# Adding and removing elements from a set Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I wan't to create a free Set that will be initialized through a mutable parameter that is changed throughout my program.I wan't the set to contain only one value the value of the parameter each time is changed,but i can't add and remove the values from the set.If it was a list it could be done like so:

```
model.iter=RangeSet(0,1000)
model.ir=[]
model.count1=Param(mutable=True)

def solve_function(model,instance):

    instance=model.create_instance()

    for i in instance.iter:
        if i==value(instance.count):
            instance.ir.append(i)
        else:
            pass
    results= opt.solve(instance)

    instance.solutions.load_from(results)
    .#some code
    .
    .
    .
    instance.ir=[]
```

Can anybody tell me how to do the same thing with a Set() object?

Comment: Could you add more detail to your model showing how you want to use instance.ir in variable or constraint declarations?

Comment: The set instance.ir is indexing a report parameter that is used to sum up my results after each solve of my model.The parameter count is changed within a loop and the solve function is called inside the same loop.The model is quite big to upload. Everything else works fine. I have solved the problem temporarily by making the report parameter a simple dictionary and the set ir a list, as shown in the code above but i was wandering if i can do it that with a Set object.

Comment: Why do you want to use a Set and Param instead of a Python dictionary and list? The only reason to really use a Set object in your model is for indexing other Pyomo modeling components (some of the Pyomo developers even avoid using Set objects altogether and use Python lists directly for indexing things). If you're just trying to store the results after each solve and you don't need prior results to build the next model then I would stick with the simple dictionary and list you're using.